# reach out to someone

Tags: idioms

Could you make me clear of the meaning of "in order to help  or **involve them?**" as the definition of <.reach out to somebody.>?

> to try to communicate with a person or a group of people, usually in order to help or **involve them**

What does it mean by that? Involving them means to help them?

*The new mayor is reaching out to inner city communities to involve them in his plans for the city.*

So,  the new mayor is to help inner city communities by involving them in his plans?

.

P.S: Cambridge dictionary.
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ko/%EC%82%AC%EC%A0%84/%EC%98%81%EC%96%B4/reach-out-to-sb

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of this current ELL question, it's useful to note [*the difference between **implicature** and **entailment***](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/17410/what-is-the-difference-between-implicature-and-entailment) (as asked on Stack Exchange Linguistics some years ago).

Briefly, an ***implicature*** is something *unstated but implied* by an utterance. In the context of the verb ***to reach out***, the implication / implicature is expressed by *usually in order to help or involve them* in the definition.

***But*** implicatures are "cancellable", meaning that other parts of the conversation, and/or the general context itself, may make it obvious that *on any specific occasion*, an implication may not in fact apply. This is different to an ***entailment*** - which is basically, an "implication" that ***can't*** be "cancelled / overridden".

In OP's case, the cited definition clearly states that the meaning of metaphoric ***reach out*** is ***communicate*** (with people one doesn't normally interact with), not ***help***. Whilst it's very likely that the mayor does indeed intend to help those inner city communities, that's just an ***implication*** - it's not what the words themselves mean (nor is it an ***entailment***).

In some other context (probably not the current one), the mayor might "reach out" to other parts of the community simply ***to seek their advice***, with no special implication that this is in order to actually help the advice-givers.